# Why does python print() function print a % at the end of the line when I use the end parameter?

Tags: python, printing

I wanted to simulate a lotto draw by creating a lotto_pool tuple and then drawing a combination of four numbers and letters using the choice method.  I then wanted to print the results on a single line with no spaces.

I thought that it would be simple to just use the print function with the end='' parameter in a for loop.

So far, so good, the code works as expected....except that the print function always prints a % at the end of the loop, for example:

```
17a8%
```

I don't know where this % sign is coming from.  Can someone take a look at my code and clarify this for me?

```
from random import choice

lotto_pool = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "a", "e", "i", "o", "u")

for x in range(0,4):
    print(choice(lotto_pool),end='')
```

Comment: Presumably because `%` is your shell prompt - there's no newline at the end of your output, so whatever gets printed next (e.g. in a Python REPL it's the `>>>` prompt) appears immediately after the final character from the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not come from Python, it comes from *your shell*, with two possibilities:

- `%` is literally your shell prompt, since you don't have a final linefeed it's tacked onto the final line of your output
- or if you're using fish or zsh, they add a `%` before inserting their own linefeed, so that the prompt is at the right place but you're still notified that the binary is behaving strangely

#### sh/ksh/bash

```sh
~ $ echo -n "hello shell"
hello world~ $ |
```

note that the shell prompt is tacked at the end of the output, rather than be a the familiar column 0

#### zsh / fish

```sh
~ $ echo -n "hello shell"
hello zsh% 
~ $ |
```

Prompt is at its normal position, and the shell has told you that the utility behaved oddly (because no final linefeed).

(nb: on my system using zsh, the `%` being automatically inserted is also in inverted colors to be even more noticeable).